# OneToMany not working in Hibernate (org.hibernate.AnnotationException)

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey-2.0, hibernate-onetomany

I know there are alot of topics about this problem, but none of them are like this (As most people actually forget to use mappedBy propertly).
But I'm entirely sure this code is right and thus i'm completely stuck on this issue:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: xx.xx.xx.AlarmEntity.userAlarm in xx.xx.xx.UserEntity.userAlarms
```

Using Hibernate v5.* with Jersey.
The code I use in mapping (in UserEntity):

```
   @OneToMany(targetEntity = AlarmEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="userAlarm")
private List<AlarmEntity> userAlarms;
```

And in AlarmEntity:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private UserEntity userAlarm;
```

Join properties exist.
it did work before in EclipseLink, but after making the switch to Hibernate I keep getting this error. (I got other @OneToMany relations, but those just work... (UserEntity -> OneToMany -> AlertEntity is the other which works).

Please help.

**UPDATE**

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file, I don't if something is missing. I only have three Entities.

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="xx.xx.xx.UserEntity" />
    <mapping class="xx.xx.xx.AlertEntity" />
    <mapping class="xx.xx.xx.AlarmEntity" />
</session-factory>
```

Comment: is UserEntity  a @Entity ?

Comment: Where's your mapping configuration? post your hibernate.cfg.xml please.

Comment: @HenningLuther , yes both are! (From the javax.persistence package).

Comment: @chsdk I updated my answer with the hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: did you try without targetEntity = AlarmEntity.class ? not sure if its needed and correct

Comment: @HenningLuther yes AlertEntity (The one which is working with @OneToMany) doesn't use it. But needed to try something. I try to remove it again, to see if it works. **update, I removed it and tried again. But still no success. Anyway thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok may I just ask you why are you using `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` with `userAlarm` it's useless, and is `userAlarm` under `AlarmEntity` class?

Comment: @chsdk, didn't know that, will just remove it. Yes userAlarm is inside the AlarmEntity class.

Comment: Lol @chsdk I tried to run the project with Eclipse and it worked....... (Intellij first). Any idea why?

Comment: I think it's an IDE issue, maybe Intellij can't see the class file or maybe it has another path in intellij